# Is a bigger version of the user's default avatar available?

Tags: support, gravatar

I like my default SO avatar and want to use it on other plattforms, e.g. on github. Is it possible / where to find it in a bigger resolution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [the URL of your avatar](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ec792abc8b563e84c2ba50aadbffb9fe?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) and change `s=128` there to `s=`whatever size you want.

Example: `s=512`.

[image]

Comment: My, that's a lot of Triforces <_<

Comment: Maybe I'm missing obvious but.. how do you get the URL of the avatar ?

Comment: Found it ! Profile > Edit Profile & Settings > Right click on avatar > View image